# Who is Bruce and does he have a real-world counterpart?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, wilfred

In the episode *"Doubt"* (S01E11) of [*Wilfred*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1703925/) (the US version) *Ryan* meets a guy who introduces himself as *Bruce* and who can see *Wilfred* the way *Ryan* does. He tells him that he's been *Wilfred*'s friend once, similar to *Ryan*, but that *Wilfred* ultimately ruined his life. While he first believes *Bruce* (after *Wilfred* once again played one of his tricks on *Ryan* by luring him into a situation with a sabotaged condom, like he did with *Bruce* before), during the final conclusion when *Wilfred* and *Bruce* fight with each other he saves *Wilfred* by shooting *Bruce*. But then it turns out that this was all staged (and the gun isn't loaded with real bullets) and seems to have been a test for *Ryan*'s trust in *Wilfred*, which he finally passed.

Now given the premise that *Wilfred* is in the end something like a mentor (a pretty weird one, though) for *Ryan* to get control over his own life again, and given the title of the episode, a pretty near interpretation would be that *Bruce* symbolizes *Ryan*'s doubt in *Wilfred*'s ultimate goodwill and his overall purpose (and in the end *Ryan*'s beliefs about *Wilfred*'s intentions are permanently put to test). But while *Wilfred* is in the end a *real* dog others can see and whose behaviour is observed by others, too (albeit not in the same way like *Ryan* does), I'm not sure what *Bruce* then was. If he was a completely imaginative entity purely created by *Ryan*'s own doubts, then how could *Wilfred*, who is in fact still rooted in the *real* world (even if the particular expression of his behaviour was an imagination of *Ryan*) interact with him? But if *Bruce* has an actual *real* world counterpart (like *Wilfred*'s actual dog nature), then who was this guy?

Maybe this whole question is intended to be unanswerable or I'm just making more out of it than there is to it, but it would be really helpful if anyone could shed some light on **what *Bruce* actually is** and maybe **where the border between *Ryan*'s imagination and the real world is** in general. (Note that I haven't seen the last episode of season 1 and all the following seasons yet, but don't mind spoilers either if they can shed some light on this.)

Answer (score 1):

I watched all of *Wilfred* and personally, I interpreted Bruce to be a figment of Ryan's imagination much like the behavior of Wilfred. I do think that it is meant to be ambiguous, however, and that the shows intention was to finish with some of it's mystery intact. If you ask me, Bruce was all in Ryan's head but then again, the show never confirmed or denied his existence in the end.